# Baiting Questions and Resulting Answers

Tags: discussion

This follows my previous discussion. Some question express personal take on a matter and the response is agreeable when it is not exactly a Buddhist answer. The answers seem attractive to the poster of the question.

Comment: More than once (and not only you) I don't find it useful/meaningful to ask questions about the policy for handling types of question or answer, unless you're willing to reference some specific examples of what you're referring to -- otherwise I don't know what you're talking/asking about.

Comment: Giving an example in this context I have to point to an answer and question which are from 2 users. This might be unpopular with 2 users which I want to avoid.

Comment: Sometimes in the past we've closed 'rhetorical' questions which aren't real questions and whose purpose is to promote the OP's point of view ... so that (i.e. closing questions which aren't questions) is the current policy. On the other hand I haven't noticed any recent questions which IMO probably fit that policy and therefore ought to be closed.

Comment: I am not saying about the question but mostly on the answer. Question like I think according to Buddhism x then answers say you are right will justification when x is wrong or not be exactly so. When this happen from established users it can be misleading but let's see if this continues in which case I will bring up who the user is.

Comment: If it's *not* about the question, then maybe this is the same as [the previous meta-topic](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1978/254): i.e. how and whether to respond to answers which you disagree with and read as being "contrary to Buddhist doctrine".

Comment: Yes. This adds one context such thing can happen.

Comment: It is not matter of my opinion or anybody else's opinion, but if Tripitaka or established work in the lineage or teacher in the same linage / school says otherwise and if this is quoted then I don't think there is any issue in responding. I am not saying what is posted should be deleted but you should say x, y, z mentioned here is my opinion and not what Buddhism says about it and if the answer is held out to be from x school / lineage then say this is my opinion and that of x school / linage.

Answer (score 1):

Upasaka Suminda Sirinath S. Dharmasena, well if one looks at which answers are marked at the best, one would see a lot of non-Dhamma-Vinaya answers marked as such.

But this is a "problem" of the origin of SE generally since it is somehow developed out of working aids. So if for example a code works for the questioner, he may mark it as the best answer.

When we come down to Dhamma-Vinaya, such a system does not work, since there are very less who would try it first if the answer works or even had the intent to find something that works.

One would even find Dhamma-Vinaya up-voted. "[What does one expect](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an10/an10.080.than_en.html)?" is maybe the most releasing answer if not thinking generally of how useful it is to dwell among people with wrong view.

Since it was just promoted on the right side of the frame here: [How does one define a non-biased, citation-worthy study?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63701/how-does-one-define-a-non-biased-citation-worthy-study)

The Buddhas message is: Give it a prove and put it into action to see if it works or not or if you have actually gained liberation on the ways you are thinking.

And "Baiting Questions" would be not really bad, but actually good, if made with the right intent. Atma guesses that 90% or more questions the Buddha raised, have been baiting questions. How ever, Atma remembers that you don't like to have teaching questions, since people prefer to teach when answering questions.

If one takes your question here, it was actually a "Baiting Question" or?

So also here: "Where do you like to go generally? Whats your aim generally?"